# The smallest memory units addressible and movable

Tags: memory, architecture, types, cpu-word, byte

These are two questions that were received under [my previous question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/91230/addressable-memory-unit):

> (1) what is the minimum amount of data (N bits) that can be moved from
>   memory to register using only one machine instruction?
>
> (2) When this machine instruction is used, what is the smallest
>   address increment that lets you read the next N bits? (not overlapping
>   with the first read)

1. I was wondering if in (1)  the minimum amount of data that can be
   moved from memory to register using only one machine instruction is
   called a word, and in (2), the smallest address increment that lets
   you read the next N bits? (not overlapping with the first read) is
   called a byte?
2. In (1), is "the minimum amount of data that can be moved from memory
   to register using only one machine instruction" same as

   - the minimum amount of data that can be moved to memory from
     register    using only one machine instruction,
   - the minimum amount of data that one machine instruction can
     operate    on, and
   - the content of a register?
3. If I am not wrong, the minimum memory units in (1) and in (2) are
   generally not the same. But I wonder why, i.e., how the smallest addressable
   memory is not

   - the smallest memory to be moved between memory and register, and
   - the smallest memory to be operated on

   by machine instructions? Can there be some assembly code to explain?

I am mainly talking about regular computer architectures, such as X86, X86-64, ....

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 0):

(1) It is called a [WORD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_%28data_type%29), you are correct. Word size varies depending on the CPU architecture, for most modern computers a word can either be 32 bits (4 bytes) or 64 bits (8 bytes).

(2) [Most modern computers and BYTE-addressible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_address)